# Ubuntu bootloop before grub

Tags: boot, grub2, uefi

This is not really a question, but my attempt to document a solution that worked for my problem.

**Symptoms**:

- After some update there was an infinite booting loop before entering grub: after showing motherboard picture for several seconds computer started a reboot. That is, I was easily able to enter BIOS to change boot order but I couldn't enter grub by holding Shift button (there was a black screen and nothing happened).
- This behavior was after updates on Ubuntu 16.04 and after installing updates on fresh Ubuntu 18.04.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What helped me was to disable CSM (Compatibility Support Module) in BIOS (exact steps to do that depend on the installed motherboard). I was able to successfully use Ubuntu after doing that.